# Ubiquiti APs radius attribute that terminates session when quota is reached

Tags: freeradius, radius

For Ubiquiti Unifi APs, is there a radius attribute that terminates the session when the set accounting quote is reached? I am want to use it for wireless clients, not hotspot or ppoe. Something like Mikrotik-Recv-Limit.

For example, a wireless network user is given 10 G a month. If the quota is reached, Unifi AP will terminate the session.

My current implementation is to set the session timeout to 1 hour. Check the quota when the session authenticates. If the quota is reached, do not authorise connection.

Jake He

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need to have a customized RADIUS server which can do that. since there are no such RADIUS attributes available you either need to send `Session-Timeout` to your NAS (Network Access Server) once the user reaches quota or disconnect using `CoA (Change of Authorization)`.